# Shiv'a Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

107 years after the Torah was translated into Greek (the Septuagint), the Chashmonaim won their victory against Hellenistic culture and its infiltration of Jewish life.

(The years of these two events are, respectively, 3515 and 3622 since Creation.)

Answer (score 4):

107 is the age (in years) יעקב was when יוסף met פרעה, in a miscalculation that assumes יעקב had not stopped to learn for fourteen years in בית עבר. (Source:‎ מגילה‎ 17a.)

Comment: Didn't Yosef actually meet Par'o when Ya'akov was 108? Ya'akov was 130 when he met Par'o, and that was after 22 years of separation from Yosef.

Comment: @Isaac, יוסף didn't meet פרעה the year he left יעקב: he was incarcerated first.

Comment: @msh210 - So, Ya'akov was 109 when Yosef met Par'o. I don't understand how a 14-year miscalculation can make that look like 107.

Comment: @Isaac, he was incarcerated with the Minister of the Butlers and the Minister of the Bakers for two years, but was in Potifar's house first.

Comment: To be exact, he was in prison for 12 years (and before that he spent a year in Potiphar's house). So when Yosef met Pharaoh, Yaakov was 121. Deduct 14 years for Shem and Ever's yeshivah, and you get 107.

Answer (score 3):

107 is the number of "folk sayings" (אמרי אינשי) that appear in the gemora Bavli, as listed in [this sefer](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/37721).